# Convert Rows to Columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I am trying to convert rows to columns in SQL server. I am trying to convert the value's a product gets while being tested during quality. I have tried the pivot function but having trouble doing so as the same values do get repeated and it can not be easily sorted into rows. The table I am trying to pivot holds ~30K data row's so hoping to find a dynamic solution for this.

The maximum number of new columns is 30 but sometimes a product doesn't get tested as much so it can be less. The new column would be based off my inspection_unit_number field. Is this possible to achieve in SQL

[Current data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSLvE.png)

[What I hope to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otcRO.png)

Current Attempt

```
SELECT BATCH , characteristic, [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30]
from
(
  select inspection_lot ,node_number    ,characteristic ,inspector  ,inspection_unit_number ,start_date ,measured_value ,original_value ,material_no    ,batch

  from stg.IQC_Tensile_TF
) d


pivot
(
  max(measured_value)
  for 
  INSPECTION_UNIT_NUMBER in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30])
) piv;
```

Comment: Honestly, your presentation should be doing this, *not* your SQL layer.

Comment: This is the way the data is being shown from the software we download it from. I am trying to clean the data before it is brought into the warehouse as currently its too difficult to read

Comment: *"This is the way the data is being shown from the software we download it from."* Huh? The desired data is denormalised; you *don't* want to store it in that format. The *image* of data you provided called "Current Data" ([please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)) should be the way you want to store the data.

Comment: If human readability is your concern when cleaning data, you're doing it wrong. It should be machine readable. In a relational database, that usually means normalised, which is what you're stating with already.

Comment: Also, yoir starting data example is missing columns present in your target data and used by your example sql. Then, in the example sql, you select columns in `d` which you then don't use in the outer query. You also don't specify what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to go for a dynamic query, check if this will suit your needs.

I created a common table expression to be able to use distinct and then order by in the stuff function:

```
DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX)

WITH cte_unique_inspection_unit_number AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT QUOTENAME('TestResults' + CAST(inspection_unit_number AS VARCHAR)) TestResultsN, 
       inspection_unit_number
FROM IQC_Tensile_TF
)

SELECT @Columns = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + TestResultsN
            FROM cte_unique_inspection_unit_number
            ORDER BY inspection_unit_number
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,2,''),

        @query = 'SELECT batch, node_number, characteristic, ' + @Columns + ' from 
            (
                select batch,
                       node_number,
                       characteristic,
                       measured_value,
                       ''TestResults'' + CAST(inspection_unit_number AS VARCHAR) TestResultsN
                from IQC_Tensile_TF
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(measured_value)
                for TestResultsN in (' + @Columns + ')
            ) p '

EXEC(@query)
```

To view the execution in fiddle:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=7898422e4422faacb25d7f3c2285f14a

If you find my answer useful, i would appreciate if you vote up and mark as accepted =D

Comment: The op specified a fixed number of columns. So, while dynamic sql is an option, it is entirely possible to pivot this data without it. (Either way, pivoting data so it can be cleaned is very likely a huge mistake.)

Comment: Hi @MatBailie! I would love to know how, I thought it would not be possible because the columns vary.

Comment: Much like the code your dynamic sql would generate and execute. But just do it for 30 columns Always. Sparse data will just return NULL values in columns where the key is not present in the data.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=609d7d8896ed34668baf40ef3fec9663

Comment: Yes this seems to get the results i am hoping for. The reason i want it for easy human reading is the data will then be used to create charts in a separate software. It becomes too complicated and too much data rows when trying to resolve it the other way.

Comment: @tomfbsc If my 20 years in the business have taught me anything, an MI / presentation layer that can't handle the original data format isn't worth using. Any software worth using can handle normalised data without requiring it to be pivoted in the database.